# Access nested json property with dashes

Tags: javascript

How do I deconstruct a nested json object where every level has dashes in the names?

`{"my-data":{"the-values":"are-you-kidding-me?"}}`

In my react app, I want to do:
`const { "my-data"."the-values": value}`

Or something similar to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructure the [nested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring) object using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring) (the brackets):

```js
const data = {'my-data':{'the-values':'are-you-kidding-me?'}}

const { ['my-data']: { ['the-values']: value} } = data

console.log(value)
```